# .htaccess with UTM parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, google-analytics

I have a .htaccess file successfully configured on my server, but would like an elegant way of telling Google Analytics where my traffic is coming from. Those utm tags in the query string are just plain ugly...

I have this (for instance):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-twitter/?$ index.php?p=a&a=$1&utm_source=TwitterFeed&utm_medium=Auto&utm_campaign=TwitterFeed [NC,QSA]
```

This successfully displays the page, but Analytics won't pick up the utm tags. Any ideas? I've googled, but nothing appropriate showing!

Comment: The rewrite of one URL to another in htaccess is happening on the server. Then google's analytics code is looking at the URL client-side (Javascript) and not seeing these server-side changes. You'll need to redirect to the new URL so google can see that stuff, maybe another solution is passing those varibles to google's code explicitly by using PHP to insert them in the code block.